# Comparing ionisation energy between an element and an ion

Tags: ionization-energy

> Choose one that has the biggest ionization energy:
>
> 1. $\ce{Br-}$ and $\ce{Kr}$
> 2. $\ce{Cl-}$ and $\ce{Ar}$
> 3. $\ce{Cl}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$

I am not sure how I can compare the ionization energy between an ion and an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With few execptions (e.g. $\ce{H+}$) where removing an electron obviously doesn't make sense, think of the atoms or ions like box which does contain electrons which after removal of an electron has one additional positive charge.  This approach does not care if you start with a neuter atom like Kr, an anion like $\ce{Cl-}$ or even a cation which already donated an electron earlier (e.g., $\ce{K+}$ or $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$).

You then compare initial state and final state, e.g. for $\ce{Br-}$ *vs.* $\ce{Br}$ yielding a difference in energy A, and the difference B while comparing $\ce{Kr}$ *vs.* $\ce{Kr+}$.  Because eventually you either compare difference A against difference B based on experimental data, or you balance your argument with which of the two differences is greater, requiring more energy to extract this one electron.  Possible criteria may be: reaching / departing a neuter state, breaking / disobeying octet rule, radii of the atoms / ions vs. how many charge the reactant / product ion / atom has to accomodate.  Sometimes, a single criterion dominates the argumentation; sometimes you need multiple criteria to consider.

Many ionization energies are tabulated (e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy#Values_and_trends)), so you may use these values as a test bed for your argumentation.